# distance beetween weakly closed sets

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, weak-topology

Is true that if X and Y are two weakly closed subsets of a Banach Space V then d(X,Y)=0  ?
I know that's true in case one of them is weakly compact but i can't understand it in this situation,

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: Your question is asking something trivial.  Perhaps you mean "... then $d(X,Y) \ne 0$" ?  And that $X,Y$ are disjoint?  Try to find a counterexample in the one-dimensional Banach space $\mathbb R$.  If you don't show your own efforts, the question is likely to be closed.

Comment: Sorry you are right. This Is my First post and i havent already understood the rules. Yes they were disjoint and thank you i have found a counterexample in R